# To Get Tag value by passing Tag name from a string in XML Parser method in Groovy

Tags: groovy, xml-parsing

How can I get the value of any tag (e.g. `Quantity`) from the below XML by passing the tag name without using hard coded tag name-

```
def temp1="""
<TradeRecord>
   <TradeId>1000</TradeId> 
   <SecurityId>10382456</SecurityId> 
   <TradeType>SELLL</TradeType> 
   <TradeDate>2014-03-21</TradeDate> 
   <Broker>100</Broker> 
   <Exchange>1</Exchange> 
   <Status>INIT</Status> 
   <Quantity>125</Quantity> 
   <ApprovedBy /> 
</TradeRecord>
"""

def records = new XmlParser().parseText(temp1)
//log.info records.Quantity[0].text()     By using this i am getting value but i want     'Quantity' to come from a string
tag = 'Quantity'
xy = records["Quantity"].value;   'This is not working
log.info xy
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do

```
records."$tag".text()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have used `.text()` method

`records[tag].text()`

Comment: Thanks Kunal, my one more query how can i set value in any of these tag which again comes from a string.

Comment: May be this is what you are looking for : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16061762/xmlslurper-how-to-change-the-text-of-a-dynamic-node

Comment: Kunal, that code is not working  for me.I want to update any tag value but that tag name and new value comes from a csv.